# Lefschetz number of $f\colon \Bbb R P^1\to \Bbb R P^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have $F\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (xy,x^2-3y^2)$. It's easy to see that such map induces a map $f\colon \Bbb R P^1\to \Bbb R P^1$. I'm asked to compute its degree and its Lefschetz number.

So the fixed point I found of $f$ are $[0;1]$, $[2;1]$ and $[-2;1]$. Notice that they are in the domain of the local chart $[x;1]\mapsto x$ so we can work with this chart only.

A quick computation of the differential in this chart gives us that $$d_{[x;1]}f=-\dfrac{x^2+3}{(x^2-3)^2}$$
If we plug in our fixed point we see that everyone of them is Lefschetz, with local lefschetz number $-1$ and therefore the Lefschetz number is $-3$.

From this we see that the degree should be $4$, thanks to the characterisation of the Lefschetz number as alternate sum of trace of maps into homology.

> But a direct computation of the degree gives us a different answer. In fact the value $[0,1]$ is regular, since its preimages $[0;1]$ and $[1;0]$ are regular points. A standard computations gives that the degree is $-2$. This would imply that the Lefschetz number is $3$ and not $-3$.

Where am I missing something?

> **EDIT:** the answer below suggests that I should compute the local Lefschtez number with $I-d_pf$ and not $d_pf-I$. Why is that the case? According to Guillemin-Pollack the second formula is the correct one.

Comment: Your question prompted me to look through books and to think about this more carefully. Guillemin & Pollack, Hirsch, Bott & Tu — all use $\det(df_x - I)$ to define the local Lefschetz number. The Poincaré-Hopf theorem, which computes the sum of the indices of a vector field $\vec v$ as the intersection number $I(Z,\vec v) = I(Z,Z) = \chi(M)$ ($Z$ being the zero section of the tangent bundle). We all expect the Lefschetz number to be $I(\Delta,\text{gr}(f))$ by analogy. Well, that does *not* agree with the homological definition of the Lefschetz number when $\dim M$ is odd.

Comment: One needs either to consider $I(\text{gr(f)},\Delta)$ or to reverse the graph (as Godbillon does), considering the mapping $x\rightsquigarrow (f(x),x)$. This will then be consistent with the homological definition of Lefschetz number, but this necessitates the local Lefschetz number's being given by $\det(I-df_x)$, as Math536 says in his answer. Sigh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The local Lefschetz number of $f$ at $[x;1]$ (where $x \in \{0,-2,2\}$) is given by
$$
L(f,[x;1]) = \mathrm{sgn} ( \det (1 - d_{[x;1]}f) ) = \mathrm{sgn} \left( 1 + \frac{x^2+3}{(x^2 - 3)^2} \right) = 1.
$$
Thus the Lefschetz number of $f$ is $3$.

Some books define the local Lefschetz number by
$$(1) \quad L(f,p) = \mathrm{sgn} (\det( d_pf - 1)) $$
instead of
$$(2) \quad L(f,p) = \mathrm{sgn} (\det( 1 - d_pf)). $$
These two definitions are *not* equivalent: they agree for even-dimensional manifolds, but differ by a sign for odd-dimensional manifolds. If you want the Lefschetz number of $f$ (defined as an alternating sum of traces of induced maps on homology) to be equal to the sum of its local Lefschetz numbers, you need to use definition (2).

> **Lefschetz fixed-point formula**: Let $M^n$ be a closed smooth manifold and $f:M \to M$ be a smooth map with nondegenerate fixed points. Then $$ \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \mathrm{Tr}(H_i(f)) = \sum_{p \in \mathrm{Fix}(f)} \mathrm{sgn}(\det(1 - d_pf))$$

Comment: Dear Math536, I thought that the local lefschetz number was given by $\det(d_pf-1)$. Why did you put a $-$ everywhere?